# Extract number from a line with awk/sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I have this string:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: vp6f, yuv420p, 852x478, 1638 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
```

and I would like to extract `25` from it.
I use:

```
sed -r 's/.+([0-9]{2} tbr).+/\1/'
```

and it returns what I need.

Anyway, if instead I encounter a string like

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11981 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
```

It won't return what I need anymore.

I tried different alternate ways so the value for `tbr` is returned in both cases but couldn't find the right expression.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one approach with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/tbr/{print $1}' RS=, file
25
29.97
```

**Explanation:**

By default `awk` treats each line as a record, By setting `RS` to `,` we set the record separator to a comma. The script looks at each record and prints the first field of any record that matches `tbr`.

---

A `GNU grep` approach that uses [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -Po '[0-9.]+(?= tbr)' file
25
29.97
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple! I would appreciate if you could "translate" me what RS=, actually does as I cannot seem to understand.

Comment: @AlexFlo added an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Your current sed command would work well if you tweak the regex a bit:

```
sed -r 's/.+ (\S+) tbr,.+/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks sudo_O, I never seem to remember to use those :/ Answer updated.